# Расположение пакета SDK для Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Как задать расположение пакета SDK для Android в VS?

В документации есть возможность указать путь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на самом деле он почему-то не отображается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как в раз на первой картинке указано на самой верхней части Android SDk Location, это и есть путь к SDk. Можете указать свой путь там же.

Comment: @Vfvtnjd Первая картинка это документация, вторая VS. В этом и проблема, что в программе почему-то нет строки для ввода пути

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782807/how-do-i-move-the-android-sdk-folder-installed-with-visual-studio-2017